# The meaning of "anonymous"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

"The face of cities in China may be anonymous, but the character of residents in these cities is different." Can anybody tell me whether the word "anonymous" is appropriate in that sentence? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you use other words to describe what idea you are trying to convey with this sentence?  Also, can you explain why you are unsure of the answer, stating the research you have already done?

Comment: I looked up anonymous. It says if you describe a place as anonymous, you dislike it because it has no unusual or interesting features and seems unwelcoming. But someone told me that this meaning of anonymous is seldom used. It is ususally used to describe a name that is not known or that is not made public.

Comment: So, I just wonder whether "anonymous" can be used here to discribe a place without any unusual or interesting features.

Comment: **The face of cities in China may be anonymous...** does not make sense. English does not speak of faces being anonymous, but rather individuals as anonymous (e.g. an anonymous writer, an anonymous donor, an anonymous contributor). I'd look up synonyms for boring -- nondescript is a good one.